# imports colliding when creating blank activity with fragment

Tags: android, eclipse, android-fragments

I am using Eclipse and when I create Blank activity with Fragment it is using

```
if (savedInstanceState == null) {  
       getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.container, new placeholder()).commit();         
}
```

in the *onCreate method* of *MainActivity* which needs `import app.fragment` and I need to use `loginbutton.setfragment(this)` in Placeholder class needs `import android.v4.app.Fragment` and I cannot import both of them together. somebody please help

Comment: post your full code, Use same import for both the fragments.

Answer (score 0):

It is advised to use Fragment or v4.Fragment thru out the project.

In your case import android.v4.app.Fragment and use getSupportFragmentManager instead of getFragmentManager